# Do customer uploaded files count towards merchant storage limit?

Tags: shopify

With Line Item Properties, it's possible to allow customers to include file attachments to product orders (http://wiki.shopify.com/Line_Item_Properties#File_attachments). These files are uploaded to http://static.shopify.com/s/files...

Do these uploaded files count towards a store's storage limit? Is there a way to list/get/delete these items either manually or through the api? Do the files persist or are they cleaned up periodically? If the customer removes the item with the file upload from their cart, is the file deleted or does it persist? If it persists, does a reference to it exist anywhere? What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine Shopify is simply eating the storage and not metering it. Storage is cheap...

Comment: Yea, I think so too, but I'd like to get an official confirmation so I can tell it to customers :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just been in touch with Shopify on this matter and they've confirmed that files uploaded to the CDN (customer uploaded files) can't be edited or deleted by the user and subsequently don't count towards a merchant's storage limit.

Apparently they are working on an API to allow customer uploads to appear in the merchant's files. I'd speculate that once this happens it *might* count towards the storage limit but for the time being it isn't a concern.