# How to delete user uploaded files on Shopify

Tags: file, upload, shopify

Well, I am facing a strange problem. Shopify allows 1GB of file storage. There are many test orders that I created and now I have deleted these. But my quota usage still shows the user uploaded files.

I would like to know how to delete user uploaded files so that I can use my storage efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a way to delete customer uploaded files.

I have the same issue:

- I created a number of test orders with an uploaded file as a line item property
- My Storage used (Admin > Settings > Account) increased by the combined size of the images
- After deleting the orders, my storage used remains unchanged (and I can still access the uploaded files on the Shopify CDN via https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/xxxxxxxxx/uploads/img_name.jpg after the order has been deleted)
- The Shopify admin only provides access to delete administrator uploaded files (Admin > Settings > Files)

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042293/do-customer-uploaded-files-count-towards-merchant-storage-limit) on Stack Overflow, and [this question](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/game-changer-added-line-item-properties-109411#comment-150075) on the Shopify discussion forums, neither of which have been answered yet.

Perhaps this should be a feature request...

**EDIT:**

Location of customer uploaded files: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/xxxxxxxxx/uploads/
Location of files uploaded via Settings > Files: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/xxxxxxxxx/files/

Comment: Thanks Steph, This is very critical for my site. I have been following up with Shopify support team for couple of days now. Here is the latest I received from them:

------------------------------QUOTE------------------------
Definitely see what you mean. I assumed the images were being uploaded to the "Files" section as I saw images in there, but I did just do a test and they are not appearing there.

If you allow me I'm going to send this to our technical team and see where the files are being stored!

Once I have an update I will let you know,
------------UNQUOTE------------